Working with html frame - not able to access the fame tag element that has been opened after clicking submit button in new html page
I am accessing the elements of the frame with ID = mainfrm, opening the page and submitting the value in input text box and after clicking submit button the html element changes of frame tag with new form id and I am not able to access the new elements of form tag of frame tag with id = mainfrm that has been appeared after submitting. Below providing the code and sample HTML
Sub ACCBAL()
    
    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim DocFrame As MSHTML.HTMLFrameElement
    

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("E7").Value
    
    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
    
    Set HTMLdoc = IE.document
    Set DocFrame = HTMLdoc.getElementById("mainfrm")
    Set HTMLdoc = DocFrame.contentDocument
    
    strt_val = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("E11").Value
    strt_val2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("E12").Value

    For rowno = strt_val To strt_val2
        HTMLdoc.getElementById("txtAccID").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A" & rowno).Value
        HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("btnSubmit")(0).Click
        
        While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
 ' This below part gives old frame data       
              
        Set HTMLFrames = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("form")
        
        For Each HTMLFrame In HTMLFrames
            Debug.Print HTMLFrame.ID
        Next HTMLFrame
        
    Next
    
End Sub

HTML PAGE 1
<html>
<head></head>
<frameset id="f1">
<frameset id="f2">
<frameset id="f3">
 <frame id = "top">
 <frame id = "mainfrm">
  <html>
   <form id = "transactionfrm">
   <table>
    <td>
     <input id="txtAccID"></td>
   </table>
   <table>
    <td>
     <input name="btnSubmit">
    </td>
   </table>
  </html>
 </frame>
</frameset>
</html>

HTML PAGE 2
<html>
 <head></head>
  <frameset id="f1">
  <frameset id="f2">
  <frameset id="f3">
   <frame id = "top">
   <frame id = "mainfrm">
    <html>
     <form id = "tranenq"> 
      <table class = "cclass">
      <td>
       <span>1245455</span>
      </td>
     </table>
     <table class = "cclass">
      <td>
       <input name="back">
      </td>
     </table>
    </html>
   </frame>
  </frameset>
</html>

I wanted to fetch the frame html elements that has been dynamically change in frame 3 mainfrm that has not been updated in HTMLdoc dynamically. Please help

Note that <frameset> has been obsolete for 20 years or more.
